# Simple SQL JOIN to get the Values of one Field based on Other Field >0

Tags: sql

Have a Table with Fields Country, Dc13, Jn14....Dc14. Values on Dc13 and Dc14 are 0 or >0.

To get the same Countries with Values i use the query that works fine:

```
SELECT Tb1.Country FROM Tb1 WHERE (((Tb1.Dc13)>0) AND ((Tb1.Dc14)>0))
GROUP BY Tb1.Country
```

I'm trying to compare and get the countries that have Value in Dc14 but 0 in Dc13. Something like that below that i cant configure:

```
SELECT Tb1.Country
FROM Tb1
JOIN Tb1.Dc14 ON Tb1.Dc13 = Tb1.Dc14
WHERE (((Tb1.Dc13)>0) AND ((Tb1.Dc14)>0))
GROUP BY Tb1.Country
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT "Dc13 Only" AS Status, Country
 FROM Tb1 AS T1
 WHERE Dc13 IS NOT NULL
 AND NOT EXISTS
 (SELECT *
    FROM Tb1 As T2
    WHERE T2.Country = T1.Country
    AND Dc14 IS NOT NULL)
 UNION
SELECT "Dc14 Only", Country
FROM Tb1 AS T1
WHERE Dc14 IS NOT NULL
AND NOT EXISTS
     (SELECT *
     FROM Tb1 As T2
     WHERE T2.Country = T1.Country
     AND Dc13 IS NOT NULL)
 UNION
 SELECT "DC13 & Dc14", Country
 FROM Tb1
 WHERE Dc13 IS NOT NULL
 AND Dc14 IS NOT NULL
 UNION
 SELECT "Neither", Country
 FROM Tb1 AS T1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
 (SELECT *
  FROM Tb1 As T2
  WHERE T2.Country = T1.Country
  AND (Dc13 IS NOT NULL
  OR Dc14 IS NOT NULL))
  ORDER BY Status, Country;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
SELECT Tb1.Country 
FROM Tb1 WHERE (((Tb1.Dc13)=0) AND ((Tb1.Dc14)>0))
GROUP BY Tb1.Country
```

Comment: Well, you should provide some test data. Try creating an SQLFiddle.com scenario, so we can look at it. From what you have said, this query should work, and the fact that it does not get any results might mean that there are no rows matching the criteria.

Comment: Country Angola
Ethiopia
Ethiopia
Ethiopia
Mauritius
Mozambique
Mozambique
South Africa
South Africa
South Africa
South Africa
South Africa
South Africa
Tanzania
Zambia
Zambia
India
India
India
India
India
India
India
India
India
India
Philippines
Philippines
Thailand
Uzbekistan

Comment: This is not really helpful, as the data you provided have only the country names but no Dc13 or Dc14 info.

Comment: Dc13 600.00
120.00
120.00
120.00
36.00
0.00
0.00
90.00
90.00
90.00
90.00
48.00
48.00
480.00
18.00
480.00
0.00
240.00
0.00
300.00
0.00
900.00

72.00
0.00
60.00
126.00
95.04
0.00
120.00

Comment: Dc14 600.00
120.00
120.00
120.00
36.00
60.00
60.00
90.00
90.00
90.00
90.00
48.00
48.00
480.00
18.00
0.00
60.00
0.00
0.00
360.00
0.00
900.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
60.00
126.00
95.04
60.00
120.00

Comment: That query does return Ethiopia and Thailand. Do you need something else?

Comment: The result should be Out Dec 14: Mauritius, South Africa. Thailand IN

Comment: Thanks GIannis. Solved the Problem.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see you are doing a query all on one table?

I think you can do this

```
SELECT Country
FROM Tb1
WHERE Dc13 = 0 AND Dc14 > 0
GROUP BY Country
```

Comment: CREATE TABLE Tb1
 (`Country` varchar(20), `Dc13` int, `Dc14` int)
;
    
INSERT INTO Tb1
    (`Country`, `Dc13`, `Dc14`)
VALUES
('Angola', 5, 5),
('Ethiopia', 0,6),
('Ethiopia', 8,8),
('Ethiopia', 60,60),
('Mauritius', 50,0),
('Mozambique', 40, 40),
('Mozambique', 100, 100),
('South Africa', 90, 0),
('South Africa', 90, 0),
('South Africa', 90, 0), 
('South Africa', 90, 0), 
('Tanzania', 90, 90),
('Zambia', 90, 0),
('Zambia', 90, 90),
('India', 90, 0),
('India', 90, 90),
('India', 90, 0),
('Philippines', 80, 80), 
('Philippines', 80, 80), 
('Thailand', 0, 80),  
('Uzbekistan', 80, 80)
;

Comment: I made an sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/56119/2 and it seemed to return results "Ethiopia", "Thailand", which is presumably what you wanted?

Comment: The result should be Out Dec 14: Mauritius, South Africa. Thailand IN.

Answer (score 0):

the only way that I found looking around is by creating 2 tables with:

```
SELECT Tb1.Country INTO Tb12  
FROM Tb1   
WHERE (((Tb1.Dc14)>0))
GROUP BY Tb1.Country;
```

and running:

```
SELECT 
  Tb11.Country,
"Country in Dc 13, but not Dc14" as Result
  FROM
 Tb11 
 LEFT JOIN Tb12 ON
   Tb11.Country = Tb12.Country
  WHERE Tb12.Country IS NULL
 UNION
 SELECT
 Tb12.Country,
      "Country in Dc14, but not Dc13"
  FROM
  Tb12
  LEFT JOIN Tb11 ON
   Tb12.Country = Tb11.Country
  WHERE Tb11.country IS NULL
 UNION
 SELECT
 Tb12.Country,
  "Country is in both Periods"
  FROM
 Tb12
 INNER JOIN Tb11 ON
          Tb12.Country = Tb11.Country
```